# Can't find the data-store of GitLab

Tags: git, nginx, gitlab

I just installed `GitLab` on my Raspberry and after hours and hours of work it's finally working, but I actually don't know why.

The `GitLab` is available at my domain "www.example.com" on Port 80

.
But:

- There is no folder at /home/ where the "/home/gitlab/gitlab/public" content should be.
- There is no "gitlab"-config file at /etc/nginx/sites-available , only default and cnl.

Maybe its colliding somehow with my OwnCloud and the Apache Server that are running.
I want to make my git available at git.example.com , but for that I need to know where to point my virtual-host at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitlab runs inside its own environment. The install is normally in `/opt/gitlab` while the data and repositories are in `/var/opt/gitlab`.

Nginx config is in `/opt/gitlab/embedded/conf/nginx.conf`.

Changing of its configuration should be done in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` though, after which you should run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.

Comment: Thx for the answer! Will give it a try when i find the time to.
Maybe i also delete apache and change everything to use nginx.